# Translation of 'I was the one who did it'

Tags: traducción, gramática

What's the correct way to translate 'I was the one who did it'? By a literal translation it would be:

> Yo fui el que lo hizo.

However, I know in Spanish the verb is often made to agree with the subject, even in slightly more 'convoluted' sentences:

> La persona más importante **soy** yo.

Does this apply to my example as well? Which is correct:

> Yo fui el que lo **hizo**.
>
> OR
>
> Yo fui el que lo **hice**.

I think this would apply to many similar sentences of a similar form as well:

> Tu fuiste el que **abriste** la puerta
>
> OR
>
> Tu fuiste el que **abrió** la puerta

Which of these is the proper translation?

Comment: Debéis acostumbraros a intentar no poner el pronombre delante puesto que en Castellano se sobreentiende. Como ves no he puesto Vosotros debéis, he puesto debéis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sentence:

> Yo fui el que lo hizo.

it can be rewritten to:

> Yo fui *la persona* que lo hizo.

or (this sentence sounds more natural):

> Yo fui quien lo hizo.

Using *la persona*, <del>Yo fui la persona que lo hice</del> sounds wrong, "la persona" and "(yo) hice" doesn't match.

**Edit**:
Replacing "el" por "la persona" in your last sentences:

> <del>Tú fuiste la persona que abriste la puerta.</del> Wrong, "la persona" and "(tú) abriste" doesn't match.
>
> Tú fuiste la persona que abrió la puerta. [OK]
> So your last sentence is the correct one.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make it sound more natural, I'd suggest something like:

> Fui yo. Yo lo hice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native speaker so I'm not sure:

For the question:

> ¿¡Quién ha sido?!

The reply would be:

> ¡He sido yo!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the third person, the correct way is:

> Yo soy aquél           (               I'm that one)
>
> Yo soy aquél   (I'm that one)
> Que cada noche te persigue     (Who chases after you every night)
> Yo soy aquél   (I'm that one)
> Que por quererte ya no vive  (Who doesn't live anymore because he loves you)
> . . .

And please note that [Raphael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael_%28singer%29) is NOT my favorite "poet".

Answer (score 0):

The most basic form (non-poetic) I would use is:

> Fui yo que lo hice.

You use the first person to maintain agreement, similar to how whenever someone talks about `seres humanos` they invariably use `nosotros` to include themselves in the statement.

Comment: Never heard that sentence (Chile).

Comment: Yo tampoco he oido esa forma de responder.